# What table structure does aide.conf expect to store the AIDE database in an SQL database

Tags: aide

This relates to the Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment.

In the aide.conf file, you are able to specify that the AIDE Database file should be saved to an SQL Database when running a command like `# aide --update`:

```
# The location of the database to be written.
#database_out=sql:host:port:database:login_name:passwd:table
#database_out=file:aide.db.new
database_out=file:@@{DBDIR}/aide.db.new.gz
```

However it is not clear what insert statement is used or what columns are required in the table.

I have tried creating a table with a BLOB column to see if the driver AIDE is using will attempt to discern what is available but got "Unsupported backend: 6". Man pages and other online resources that I have been able to find do not explain how to achieve this functionality.

How can I configure my aide.conf and SQL Table to persist AIDE databases?

Comment: I believe I have answered my own question, database support was removed, see the linked Issue. github.com/aide/aide/issues/81